webrtc freezes unity c#
I'm trying to get WebRTC to work inside of unity.
I'm trying to follow the terrible documentation of the unity webrtc package
and am running into and issue where the
// Create remote peer
var remoteConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
remoteConnection.OnDataChannel = ReceiveChannelCallback;

lines makes unity freeze.
Full Script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.WebRTC;
using System;

public class WebRTCManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RTCPeerConnection localConnection;
    private RTCPeerConnection remoteConnection;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        StartCoroutine(WebRTC.Update());

        var localConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
        var sendChannel = localConnection.CreateDataChannel("sendChannel");

        sendChannel.OnOpen = () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("DataChannel opened");
            sendChannel.Send("Hello, World!");
        };

        sendChannel.OnClose = () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("DataChannel closed");
        };

        // Create remote peer
        var remoteConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
        remoteConnection.OnDataChannel = ReceiveChannelCallback;


        // Implement the OnIceCandidate handlers
        localConnection.OnIceCandidate = e =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Candidate))
            {
                Debug.Log($"Local ICE candidate: {e.Candidate}");
                remoteConnection.AddIceCandidate(e);
            }
        };

        remoteConnection.OnIceCandidate = e =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Candidate))
            {
                Debug.Log($"Remote ICE candidate: {e.Candidate}");
                localConnection.AddIceCandidate(e);
            }
        };

        StartCoroutine(Signaling());
    }

    IEnumerator Signaling()
    {
        var op1 = localConnection.CreateOffer();
        yield return op1;
        var desc1 = op1.Desc;
        var op2 = localConnection.SetLocalDescription(ref desc1);
        yield return op2;
        var op3 = remoteConnection.SetRemoteDescription(ref desc1);
        yield return op3;
        var op4 = remoteConnection.CreateAnswer();
        yield return op4;
        var desc2 = op4.Desc;
        var op5 = remoteConnection.SetLocalDescription(ref desc2);
        yield return op5;
        var op6 = localConnection.SetRemoteDescription(ref desc2);
        yield return op6;
    }



    private void ReceiveChannelCallback(RTCDataChannel channel)
    {
        channel.OnMessage = bytes =>
        {
            Debug.Log($"Received message: {System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)}");
        };

        channel.OnOpen = () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Remote DataChannel opened");
        };

        channel.OnClose = () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Remote DataChannel closed");
        };
    }

}


I've tried following mutliple different tutorials, getting chatgpt to fix it, re-reading the documentation but all to no avail.

Where did you initalize webrtc?
